# Is it ok to register uitableviewcell in cellForRowAt.

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it ok to register uitableviewcell in cellForRowAt. Before register i will check weather that cell is register or not by dequeue and nil check. Beacuse the tableview I m using its for genreic use across app and will not be sure about kind of cell will be needed.

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textFieldCellIdentifier) as! TextFieldCell!
        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TextFieldCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: textFieldCellIdentifier);
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textFieldCellIdentifier) as! TextFieldCell!;
        }
        return cell!;
```

Comment: add  explanation of issue .

Comment: no. don't do this. Avoid memory overconsuming & increase performance. Just add in your viewDidLoad

Comment: If you design the cell in IB you don't need to register at all. And if you use the other method to dequeue a cell (with the `indexPath` parameter) you don't even need to check for `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

No it's bad.It will register multiple times  because cellForRow atIndex will call several times based on your row counts & will call if you scrolled your tableView.

So i think better to register `UITableViewCell` in `viewDidLoad` method once.

```
  tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TextFieldCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: textFieldCellIdentifier);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not OK!

Registration of cell into table is one time process.

If you will add `register(_, forCellReuseIdentifier: _)` to `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` then this registration will be done multiple times causing very small but unwanted performance issue so no need to do it.

Try putting it into `viewDidLoad()` or similar methods.

Comment: But registration will be done only if if cell == nil right ??

Comment: @AravindAR In the OP's code, cell will never be nil.

Comment: @AravindAR yeah registration will happen once.